# Como sustraer string mediante un index javascritp?

Tags: javascript, mysql

tengo un problema, estoy tratando de sustraer una subcadena dentro de una cadena mediante un index.

Por ejemplo en mysql hay una funcion SUBSTRING_INDEX(str,delim,count)

En el cual:
str = cadena
delim = //ejemplo -> '?','/','-'
count = // 1 o -1 en donde -1 significa traer la cadena de la derecha del delim y 1 lo contrario.

cod:

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX('?carro/ventana*garaje','*',-1)
```

esto me retornaria -> garaje

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX('?carro/ventana*garaje','/',1)
```

esto me retornaria -> ?carro

Entonces estoy tratando de hacer lo mismo con javascript, lo cual solo he encontrado la funcion substring() la cual solo recibe 1 o dos parametros y son numeros, no se si se puede incluir un delimitador.

Alguna sugerencia? Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Te recomiendo que uses Split, te va a convertir la cadena de texto en un array, separada por el caracter que necesites, por ejemplo:

```js
var str = "?carro/ventana*garaje";
var res = str.split("*");

console.log(res[1]);
```

La variable `res` sera un array de dos posiciones, en la segunda (el índice 1) estara "garage"

[split](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp)